# What is the event triggered for imap.end()?

Tags: node.js, imap, node-imap

I am using the **node-imap** module (https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap). I want to close the connection to the mail server using the API function 
`imap.end()`. What event should I listen to for the result.
I tried to listen for the 'end' event but it never occurred.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [documentation](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#connection-events), there is also a `close` event which is emitted when the connection has completely closed.

I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/issues/394) where a user asked whether to use `end` or `close` and the author of the package responded:

> 'close' is always emitted, you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

Either the client or the server can close the connection. No matter who does it, it's done. The client can just close the connection, it doesn't need to fill in a form in triplicate, ask the server for permission, and then receive an acknowledgement from the server.

Polite clients do send a `logout` command. I expect `imap.end()` does that.